# Is there a limit as to how many items can be referenced in a single change set?

Tags: change-set

Is there a documented limit as to how many items can be referenced in a single change set? I haven't come across any documentation discussing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Change sets are limited to 10,000 files. If your change set exceeds this limit, you can create separate change sets for email templates, dashboards, and reports. These components are often the most numerous and have fewer dependencies.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_best_practices.htm&type=5